# Getting redirected to initial activity when trying to launch my third activity on android studios

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to make an app where I launch a third `Activity` from the second activity which in turn was launched by the first `Activity` . Whenever I attempt to launch the third `Activity` however the app pauses for a second then resumes on the initial activity **without crashing**

I've posted my code below in case that helps!

```
int ranNum = (int)(Math.random()*playerNames.size());
        String location = res.getStringArray(R.array.location)[(int)(Math.random()*res.getStringArray(R.array.location).length)];
        time = Integer.getInteger(timeSelection.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Intent gamePrep = new Intent(this, GamePrep.class);
        gamePrep.putExtra("time", time);
        gamePrep.putExtra("playerNames", playerNames.toArray());
        gamePrep.putExtra("numPlayers",numPlayers);
        gamePrep.putExtra("spyPlayer",playerNames.get(ranNum));
        gamePrep.putExtra("location", location);
        gamePrep.putExtra("roleList", locationRoles.get(location));
        gamePrep.putExtra("curPlayerNum", 0);
        startActivityForResult(gamePrep,1);
```

Edit: Here's the GamePrep onCreate() code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_prep);
    curPlayerNum = getIntent().getIntExtra("curPlayerNum", 0);
    numPlayers = getIntent().getIntExtra("numPlayers", 0);
    time = getIntent().getIntExtra("time", 5);
    playerNames = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("playerNames");
    spyPlayer = getIntent().getStringExtra("spyPlayer");
    location = getIntent().getStringExtra("location");
    roleList = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("roleList");
    curPlayer = playerNames[curPlayerNum];
    isSpy = curPlayer.equals(spyPlayer);
    next = findViewById(R.id.revealButton);
    nameOutput = findViewById(R.id.nameOutput);
    locationOutput = findViewById(R.id.locationOutput);
    roleOutput = findViewById(R.id.roleOutput);
    res = getResources();
    next.setText(res.getText(R.string.reveal));
    nameOutput.setText(curPlayer);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (curPlayerNum + 1 != playerNames.length) {
                if (!revealed) {
                    reveal();
                    revealed = true;
                    if(curPlayerNum+1 != playerNames.length) {
                        next.setText(res.getString(R.string.nextPlayer));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        next.setText(res.getString(R.string.begin));
                    }
                }
                else
                    {
                    nextPlayer();
                    revealed = false;
                    next.setText(res.getString(R.string.reveal));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                startGame();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the first classes onCreate()

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_screen);
    openIntent = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    openIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, GameMenu.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        }
    });
}
```

I don't have on resume methods for either activity.
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Please add the code for `GamePrep`. most importantly the `onCreate()` method and `onResume()` as well as anything that is called in `onCreate()`

Comment: I just did! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: My suggestion would be just start simple debugging--comment out all none critically relevant code inside the `onCreate()` for instance comment out all `getIntent()` code lines and set default values for any of the variables and just start from there slowly uncommenting code lines to see where the error occurs.

Comment: I just tried commenting out everything but the basic code to launch intent and it's still sending me back to the original screen.

Comment: No error stack in the logcat? You might also start throwing in a couple of `Log.d()` in your code to see how far the code goes and where it is stopping

Comment: I just found one I must have missed it my first time through. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is yet but I at least have something to look for. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code of your first Activity, i think the issue is on the onCreate() or onResume() method.

However you make many operations like find random a number with the param playerNames.size(). All this lines can take a lot of times (may be average 1 sec) to execute.

Comment: I added the code from my first Activity hopefully it helps out, and I'll work on cutting that down. Thanks again for the help!